# How to automatically submit form seconds after TextBox has been filled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a Self Checkout page that after Customer scanning their barcode in Welcome page, then redirect to Confirmation page.

I've been using `OnTextChanged` Event with `AutoPostBack` set to True, but nothing happened after I tried to fill the `TextBox`, seems like `AutoPostBack` not working after I filled the `TextBox`.

Here is my code :

```
asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtID" CssClass="form-control form-control-lg" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtID_TextChanged"
```

Code Behind :

```
Protected Sub txtID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtID.TextChanged
    Dim barc As String = txtID.Text
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("Cart.aspx?barc={0}", barc))
End Sub
```

I expect that after `TextBox` has been filled in Welcome page, redirect to Confirmation page without any mouse click or Enter pressed but the actual result is I have to click in any place in the page.

Comment: AutoPostback on a text box  is triggered when the control loses focus. So you would need to TAB out of the field, or click elsewhere on the page. Seems like that would be defeating the purpose of auto posting

Comment: You mean by adding some OnKeyPress function  ?

Comment: Adding an OnKeyPress function won't help you because firstly if you are using a scanner, the are no key-presses and secondly as Matthew already mentioned, the event will only fire once the textbox blurs (loses focus).

Comment: @Ted If it is a wedge style scanner, which is most likely the case, it will emulate the enter key after scan. You could detect the `Keys.Enter` condition in the Keys events. Of course you can disable the functionality on the scanner, but all the ones I bought/setup ship with this feature enabled by default.

Comment: Amazing, Thank you all for your comments :) 
I just recently know that Barcode Scanner has a function to emulate Enter Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a magnitude of ways to doing this but the most simple is often the best so here's some vanilla JavaScript:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <script>
        let timer;
        //(2.5 seconds):
        let timeLimit = 2500;  
        let txtTracked = document.getElementById('TextBox1');

        //When the user stops typing, start the countdown
        txtTracked.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            if (txtTracked.value) timer = setTimeout(typingFinished, timeLimit);
        });

        ////The timer has run out:
        function typingFinished() {
            //do something
            alert("User has finished typing");
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

The above JavaScript will track a specific control (in this case the TextBox) using its ID, after 2.5 seconds of the user not typing it will post the form to your code behind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it :)